# tf broadcasting and listening in the same node

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, tf-listener, tf-broadcaster, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently trying to make a perception part using tf.

My robot 's position is broadcasted to tf, and the robot tries to read obstacles using tf.
I want to put this on the same node " " test1 "passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
"Message is generated.

What happens when two nodes tf each succeed, and one node should not?

I think this problem is "time" and I have put in various times.
ros :: Time (), ros :: Time (0). ros :: Time :: now (), ros :: Time :: now () - ros :: Duration (0.1) etc ..

But it was not all.

I tested with two threads on one node, which was a success. What is the problem?

```
#include "tf/transform_listener.h"
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "tf_b");
  tf::TransformBroadcaster br;
  
  tf::Transform transform;
  tf::Quaternion q;
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  transform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
  q.setRPY(0, 0, 0);

  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
  while (ros::ok()) {

    ros::Time tGetTime = ros::Time::now();

    transform.setRotation(q);

    br.sendTransform(
        tf::StampedTransform(transform, tGetTime, "world", "test1"));

    tf::TransformListener listener;

    try {

      listener.waitForTransform("/test1", "/world", tGetTime,
                                ros::Duration(0.1));

      tf::StampedTransform transform;
      listener.lookupTransform("/test1", "/world", tGetTime, transform);

      ROS_INFO_STREAM(transform.getOrigin().getX());

    } catch (tf::TransformException &ex) {
      ROS_ERROR(ex.what());
    }

    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

On top of that I've simplified the code to make it easier to understand.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308806/tf-broadcasting-and-listening-in-the-same-node/) by [EunsanJo](https://answers.ros.org/users/38585/eunsanjo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I think this problem is "time"

that might be, but perhaps not in the way you think.

You create your `TransformListener` *inside* your `while` loop. Don't do that. It needs *time* to fill its buffer, and you don't give it any.

Create it right after your `NodeHandle`, and use an `AsyncSpinner`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EunsanJo](https://answers.ros.org/users/38585/eunsanjo/) on 2018-11-17**:
Thank you. You are the best.
I succeeded because I put 'listener creator' outside 'while loop'!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-17**:
Using an `AsyncSpinner` might still be a good thing to do, just to avoid blocking updates to your `TransformListener` with long running operations.